# How could I turn this block into a loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm thinking that what I have to do is create a list that contains Jan, Feb, Mar, etc. and another with the letters between E and P. However, I'm still terrible at setting up loops, and out of fear I tend to write things the long way (and have many unnecessary lines because of it). Any suggestions on how to set it up?

```
JanGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("E57").Value
FebGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("F57").Value
MarGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("G57").Value
AprGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("H57").Value
MayGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("I57").Value
JunGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("J57").Value
JulGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("K57").Value
AugGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("L57").Value
SepGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("M57").Value
OctGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("N57").Value
NovGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("O57").Value
DecGroup = MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("P57").Value
```

Comment: `range("e57").offset(0,x-1).value` where x is a for next loop from 1 to 12

Comment: What you actually need here is not a loop but an `Array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use the following code:

```
Dim MthGroup As Variant
MthGroup = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(MEPF.Sheets("Group NBD-AP Goals").Range("E57:P57")))
```

you could then access your variables as `MthGroup(1)` instead of `JanGroup`, `MthGroup(2)` instead of `FebGroup`, etc.

(The two `Transpose` commands are used to convert the data from a two-dimensional `1 To 1, 1 To 12` array into a one-dimensional `1 To 12` array.)

---

Having the data in an array then allows you to use a loop elsewhere in your code, such as:

```
Dim mth As Long
For mth = 1 To 12
    MsgBox "Data for " & MonthName(mth) & " is " & MthGroup(mth) 
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible code, that will solve some of your problems and may show you how to proceed with your task:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rngCell             As Range
    Dim lngCounter          As Long
    Dim myArray(12)         As Long

    Set rngCell = Cells(57, 5) 'That is E57
    For lngCounter = 0 To 11

        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(0, 1)
        rngCell = lngCounter
        myArray(lngCounter) = rngCell.Value

    Next lngCounter

    For lngCounter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        Debug.Print myArray(lngCounter)
    Next lngCounter

End Sub
```

In general, we set Cells(57,5) as `rngCell` and we write to all cells from E57 to  P57 the numbers from 0 to 11. Thus, you see how this is done. Furthermore, we create an array named `myArray` with 12 places in it. On each loop we add a value to the array - `myArray(lngCounter) = rngCell.Value`. I have added a second loop, so you can see how to iterate through this array. It prints the values of the array to the immediate window. Cheers!